# Como recuperar o valor do boolean de retorno de um serviço REST em Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Eu tenho um serviço Java/Jersey que retorna um Boolean pro AngularJs. No meu controller, eu pego o valor do retorno do promise, mas ele me retorna um Object. Em outros casos, como um retorno de uma entidade Usuario, por exemplo, funciona de boa, pq eu pego os atributos do objeto retornado. Agora quando retorna apenas um boolean, como faço pra recuperar o valor?

Abaixo um exemplo que estou utilizando:

Serviço Java:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/verificaEmail")
public Boolean verificarEmail(String email){

    SimpleEntityManager simpleEntityManager = new SimpleEntityManager(persistenceUnitName);

    IUsuarioBusiness usuarioB = new UsuarioBusiness(simpleEntityManager);

    Boolean result = usuarioB.verificaEmail(email);

    return result;

}
```

Controller AngularJs:

```js
this.cadastrarUsuario = function() {

  var usuario = {
    email: this.usuarioLogin.email,
    senha: this.usuarioLogin.senha,
    nome: this.usuarioLogin.nome
  }

  var verificaEmail = VerificaEmail.email(usuario.email);

  verificaEmail.$promise.then( 
    function success(result)
    {
      if (result) {
        $scope.erro = true;
        $scope.mensagemErro = "Email já existe!";
        $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
        $scope.setClasseErro();
      }
    })};
```

Service:

```js
var servicoLogin = angular.module('servicoLogin', ['ngResource']);

servicoLogin.factory('VerificaEmail', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/GameService/webserver/usuario/verificaEmail', {}, {
      email: {method:'POST'}
    });
  }]);
```

Só estou pedindo ajuda pq já quebrei a cabeça e não consegui resolver esse problema que parece ser simples.

Comment: Poste o json que está sendo retornado

Comment: Como é essa função `VerificaEmail.email(usuario.email)`? Ela usa o `$http` para fazer a requisição?

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa, estou usando o angular-resource. Coloquei a função no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno o retorno é um json com apenas "false" ou "true"

Comment: Se `result` é sempre `"true"` ou `"false"`, o `if(result)` é sempre verdadeiro (porque você está lidando com strings no JS).

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema me parece ser mesmo o uso do `ngResource`, este módulo foi feito para se consumir serviços RESTfull, e por isso ele me parece estar esperando que a resposta vinda do WebService seja um objeto, quando ele recebe um `boolean` ele não consegue tratar corretamente este valor e ele não chega a ser passado para a sua função.

Eu diria que suas alternativas são a de não usar o `ngResource` e fazer a requisição diretamente usando o `$http`, ou então encapsular sua resposta em um objeto no lado do servidor.

Comment: eu acabei optando por criar um objeto no server pra conseguir fazer funcionar. Só acho estranho o ngResource não dar suporte a esse tipo de retorno, mas como não encontrei nada na internet tratando desse caso, vai do jeito mais fácil rs. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @EduardoMartins este comportamento é exatamente o esperado. Como o Leandro comentou, REST prevê retornos de objetos em notação JSON (ex. `{'resultado':'true'}`), não valores primitivos (`true`). Neste caso, utilize `$http`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver colocando o retorno em um map ou em Objeto:

```
Map<String, Object> resposta = new HashMap<String, Object>();
resposta.put("resultado", Boolean.TRUE);
```